# Creating a Material Icons subset

Tags: fonts, google-material-icons, woff2

I'm only using a few Material Icons icons, and thought that loading the entire library is a waste of resources.

I tried to edit the [original woff2 file](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v55/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) and remove all icons that I don't use. The closest I got is using this tool:
http://fontstore.baidu.com/static/editor/index-en.html#

But when I export the modified file, it doesn't work like the original one. This HTML for example doesn't render as an icon:
`<span class="material-icons">check_circle</span>`

I added the needed CSS rules as [instructed in Google's guide](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-2-self-hosting). Everything works when I self-host the *original* woff2, file but breaks when I modify it. It only works if using pseudo-elements with Unicode as the `contnet`. It seems like saving the file strips the mapping of names to icons (if it makes any sense, as I'm not familiar with how woff2 files work).

Is there a way to create a subset of the woff2 file that works like the original?

Comment: Just to add my two cents after a frustrating afternoon, that font relies on ligatures. If you inspect the TTF version of the font, for example using https://fontdrop.info/, you'll notice a lot of ligature definitions. Subsetting must preserve those ligatures. So far I'm unable to do that as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example that subsets the `thumb_up` and `thumb_down` glyphs and ligatures.

```sh
  fonttools subset MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf \
    --unicodes=5f-7a,30-39,e8db,e8dc \
    --no-layout-closure \
    --output-file=o.woff2 \
    --flavor=woff2
```

What this says is:

- `--unicodes=5f-7a`: include the glyphs for `_`, the letters `a-z` and the digits `0-9`. From what I understand, the font cannot recognize `thumb_alt` as a ligature unless the individual glyphs `t`, `h`, `u`, ... are defined (even though we will never ask the font to render an individual letter glyph).
- `...e8db,e8dc`: specify the glyphs you actually need in your subset.
- `--no-layout-closure`: include only the ligatures for the glyphs we need (`thumbs_up` and `thumbs_down`), not any other ligatures that can be constructed from the set `_a-z`, like `add`, `delete`, `face` and so on. Without this option, the subset grows to pretty much the whole set.

You can inspect the resulting file, for example on [fontdrop.info](https://fontdrop.info/), and it will show 30 glyphs and two ligatures. You can use the file as documented in [the guide](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/), in my case:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../../fonts/o.woff2') format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

To find the Unicode values of the glyphs you need, you can look at the [codepoints file](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.codepoints).

Comment: Very helpful! But Fontdrop can't show woff2 files, I use Font Forge instead. Switch to the compact view in the settings to only see the existing glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

I think [subset-iconfont](https://github.com/dzhuang/subset-iconfont) might meet your needs. The purpose of this package is to subset from several icon font packages and use the latest fontawesome css/scss styles. For your purpose, you can do it in a few lines:

```
npm install --save-dev subset-iconfont material-icons @material-design-icons/svg
```

then

```js
import { MiProvider} from 'subset-iconfont';

const mi = new MiProvider(['alarm-on'], {
  formats: ['ttf', 'woff2'],
});

fa.makeFonts('./outputDir').then((result) => {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

[image: result of the demo]

Then in folder `./outputDir` find the result, open the generated `index.html` to see  how to use it. As you might find, it will subset all the styles available of a single icons. That's why you'll get multiple font files in the webfonts direcory.

Besides, you can only keep the font files if you don't need the css/scss stuff.

P.S., I'm the author of the package.